# How do I initialize both a structure containing a const char* and the const char* itself on same line?

Tags: c, struct, constants

I have two lines that work fine but I think it's possible to combine the two statements together.

```
struct Resolver_Data
{
   const char * radio_brand;
   const char * radio_modno;
} radio_data;

int main(){
    const char * text_1 = "Syncromatic";     //these two on one line

    radio_data.radio_brand = text_1;       //these two on one line
}
```

I've tried a couple of different ideas but nothing proved fruitful.

How do I initialize both a structure containing a `const char*` and the `const char*` itself on same line?

Answer (score 4):

You can use this:

```
const char *text_1 = radio_data.radio_brand = "Syncromatic";
```

This creates both `text_1` and sets `radio_data.radio_brand` in one line.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it in a one-liner, like this:

```
int main(void) {
  radio_data.radio_brand = "Syncromatic";
}
```

Comment: I think the OP needs `text_1`, too.

Comment: Glad you posted an answer that covers the possibility of this need.